# Cannot use statement outside a module and Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, electron-packager

I'm trying to build a .exe file of my VueJS project.
For that, I want to use Electron and electron-packager.

I'm facing some issues when launching the .exe app created with the command : `electron-packager . --all`. The first one was:

[image]

I found on the internet that I had to add `"type":"module"` and `"module":"es2015"` in my `package.json` file. I added it and then I have another problem which is:

[image]

I really don't know what to do with this.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "hihihihi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type":"module",
  "module":"es2015",
  "description": "hihihihi",
  "author": "Hihihi Hihihi <hihi.hihi@hihi.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "src/background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/js": "^5.9.55",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "deepmerge": "^1.5.2",
    "electron": "^13.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.34.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you found a solution for this ?